# Is my Directional Symmetry java algo correct?

Tags: java, algorithm

Using these values:

```
double[] predicted = {2,2,3};
double[] expected = {2,1,3};
```

... the below Directional Symmetry java algo is giving me 100% despite the directional difference between the predicted and the expected array: 2,2 VS 2,1

```
double d = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < expected.length || i < predicted.length; i++) {
    double ex_i = expected[i];
    double ex_i_ = expected[i-1];
    double pr_i = predicted[i];
    double pr_i_ = predicted[i-1];

    if(((ex_i-ex_i_)*(pr_i-pr_i_))>=0) {
        d+=1;
    }
}
return (100/(expected.length-1))*d;
```

Is it normal for the Directional Symmetry or is my algo wrong ?

Comment: Could you reference the algorithm you have tried to implement? Should the denominator be `(d*(expected.length-1))`?)

Comment: I tried to find back the source of the algorithm without success. Your way it gives me 25% for the predicted value {2,2,3} even if I change it to {2,1,3}

Answer (score 1):

Ah. I found this as a reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_symmetry_%28time_series%29 It looks like when t_(i) = t_(i-1), d_i = 1, because (t_i - t_(i-1))(t^*i - t^*(i-1)) will then be 0. However, this seems like a bad test, because (t^*i - t^*(i-1) may be non-zero and this will throw off the measure.

I think the test should really be:

If (t_i - t_(i-1)) has the same sign as (t^*i - t^*(i-1)) or if (t_i - t_(i-1)) = (t^*i - t^*(i-1)) = 0,

then d_i = 1,

else

d_i = 0.

Note: I used t^ not as an exponential, but as "t hat", as in the Wikipedia link.

To be precise: It looks like your algorithm works as is described in that article, but I have my doubts that the article listed provides a statistically meaningful test.

Comment: Thanks Zéychin for your time. I guess I had to post the question on math.stackexchange.com because if an inverse direction is equal to 0  and same direction equal to 1, then what would be the state for 'flat' direction? maybe 0.5... or maybe that's why it exist a 'weighted directional symmetry' :)

Comment: It should still have a full weight of 1.0, I would think, but only if  (t_i - t_(i-1)) = (t^i - t^(i-1)) = 0. If only one of (t_i - t_(i-1)) and  (t^i - t^(i-1)) are 0, then this is a mismatch (one did not change and one did change).

Comment: Oh, and no problem. :).